# input pattern - украинские буквы?

Tags: html5

В текстовом поле указан **pattern**:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Имя" pattern="[A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё]{2,20}" />
```

Он **не воспринимает** украинские буквы: і, ї

Валидацию проходит только русский и английский язык. Формой будут пользоваться в Украине, нужна поддержка украинских букв. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: так добавьте их явно в паттерн, после ё

Comment: Может `<html lang="uk-UA">` или вроде того поможет...

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, <html lang="uk-UA"> проверил - не помогло

Comment: @Mike, действительно) так и сделал, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Имя" pattern="[A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁёІіЇїЄє]{2,20}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

В шаблоне для имен от "ov seo" не хватает нескольких важных символов, которые могут содержаться в имени, например такие как буква Ґ и апостроф (В’ячеслав, Дар’я, ...).

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Имя" name="name" pattern="[A-Za-zА-Яа-яґҐЁёІіЇїЄє'’ʼ\s-]{2,20}{2,50}">
```

Почему в шаблоне 3 апострофа? Существует 3 распространенных символа апострофа, которые используются в украинском языке - подробнее читайте на [Вики](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84), все они присутствуют в регулярном выражении.

Не стоит забывать и о составных именах, которые могут писаться через тире и пробел.

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение!